# Analyzing LLVM IR instruction

Tags: llvm-ir

I'm trying to analyze the following llvm-ir instruction:

```
    %0 = call nonnull {}* inttoptr (i64 140019712366044 to {}* ({}*, i64)*)({}* inttoptr (i64 140019153768096 to {}*), i64 0)
```

I couldn't find any information on what is `{}*` in the [docs](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html). Is it a pointer to an empty struct ?

What does this instruction do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a pointer to an empty struct ?

Yup. Somewhat like a void pointer. `void*` is not a valid type in LLVM IR, most frontends use `i8*` for this purpose.

> What does this instruction do ?

It's an indirect call. That first `{}*` is the return type of the callee (and guaranteed to be a `nonnull` pointer at that!), the callee is the value `i64 140019712366044` casted to pointer to function that returns `{}*` and takes two parameters, `{}*` and `i64`. Then for the first parameter, it passes this function `i64 140019153768096` casted to `{}*` and 0 as the second parameter.

Those constant numbers suggest that this is a JIT and those are pointers to things outside this LLVM IR module.